# Linux command to run script at intervals

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command

I have this command that I run from a terminal in ubuntu

```
python2.5 /home/me/web/gae/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py /home/me/web/gae/APPLICATION/trunk
```

I need to stop this running and then restart it every 10 seconds - I can run this from a .sh file if necessary.

What would be the best way to do this? I'd like it to all be in one script if possible so **not** that keen on using cron jobs to run it - surely there is some way of doing a loop with a delay in purely in a shell script?

The closest equivalent I can think of is JavaScript's `setInterval(function(),10000);`

Comment: Why not use cron? Seems like the right tool for this job.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
while true; do
  python2.5 /home/me/web/gae/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py /home/me/web/gae/APPLICATION/trunk &
  sleep 10
  kill $!
done
```

I.e.: Loop forever (`while true`), start the python script in background, wait for 10 seconds (`sleep 10`) and kill the background process (`kill $!`).

Comment: That's `setTimeout()`, not `setInterval()`.

Answer (score 5):

I like ~$ watch -n sec command

i.E.

```
watch -n 10 ls /home/user/specialdata

watch -n 30 csync /dir/A /remote/dir/B
```

Comment: I think this assumes that the process being watched terminates, whereas the OP is running a server process that needs to be killed. But I wasn't aware of watch so thanks for the tip-off.

Comment: Can we give time interval in milliseconds with watch command ?

Answer (score 1):

there is [`sleep`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sleep) and [`at`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?at) if you don't like [`cron`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?crontab+5)

```
echo "print after 3min again"
sleep 180  # or sleep +3m
echo "hello again, 3min passed"
```

Read the man pages, play with those a bit, and I think it'd be easy to build what you want, around those.